# would code after $this->redirect() continue running in Yii controller?

Tags: php, yii

when I write something like

```
$this->redirect('anotherRoute');
```

am I need to write

```
Yii->app()->end();
```

after it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

When in doubt, follow the code.

CController's [redirect method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail) has a second parameter named terminate, with a default value of true.

That method then calls CHttpRequest's [redirect method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#redirect-detail), passes along the `$terminate` variable, and then calls `Yii::app()->end()` if `$terminate` is `true`; which it is by default if you do not specify the second parameter yourself.